# AngularJS: How to run code before ng-repeat starts?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

i have ng-repeat on two custom directives I've created - `node` and `specialNode`:

```
   <node data="currentNode" specialNodes="specialNodesArray"
                         ng-repeat="currentNode in nodesArray">
   </node>
   <specialNode ng-repeat="currentNode in specialNodesArray">
   </specialNode>
```

Each `node` is a directive, and this is its link function:

```
if (scope.data.isSpecial) {
    scope.specialNodes.push( {data: scope.data, jqueryElement: element});
}
```

This is the code of the controller which inits the `nodes` and `specialNodesArray` members:

```
// The main nodes array
    $scope.nodesArray = [ 
{id: "1", title: "node1", isSpecial: true},
{id: "2", title: "node2", isSpecial: false},
{id: "3", title: "node3", isSpecial: true}
];

// The special nodes array which is build
$scope.specialNodesArray= [ ];
```

`nodesArray` and `specialNodesArray` are connected - the `specialNodesArray` is built from within the `node` directive. 
Each item at `specialNodesArray` holds the origin data of the created `node` (which was created at the first ng-repeat) and also holds its jquery element (we need it for later use, for scrolling animations).

The problem is that when `nodesArray` changes (by the external scope, for instance), I need to empty `specialNodesArray` before `node`'s ng-repeat is triggered.

How do I run code before ng-repeat starts? is there another way of doing it? am I doing the entire thing totally wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: What changes are you talking about? Addition/deletion of nodes or attributes edition or both?

Comment: Why can't you use `currentNode in nodesArray | filter:{isSpecial:true}` instead of constructing `specialNodesArray`?

Comment: your code is a liitle bit difficult to anderstand. but if you set nodesArray to new values just set specialNodesArray to []. Angular did the rest for you...

Comment: Not sure that the node directive is the right place to populate the special nodes array. Either do what @dfsq suggests with the filter and scrap the special nodes array or populate the special nodes array in the controller.

Comment: Hi, the changes are the special nodes that can be inserted to the bound 'specialNodesArray' collection. Unfortunately i can't use 'filter' because the second ng-repeat is connected to the 'specialNodesArray' collection, that can be changed when a new <node> directive instance has 'isSpecial=true'.

Answer (score 0):

According to [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat), ng-repeat directive executes at priority level 1000.

So if you want directive on same element with ng-repeat to be executed first, make it priority: 1001.

```
.directive('specialNode', [function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        priority: 1001,
        ...
    }
}]
```

> ***priority*** - When there are multiple directives defined on a single DOM
>   element, sometimes it is necessary to specify the order in which the
>   directives are applied. The priority is used to sort the directives
>   before their compile functions get called. Priority is defined as a
>   number. Directives with greater numerical priority are compiled first.
>   The order of directives with the same priority is undefined. The
>   default priority is 0.

Comment: The problem with this answer, is that he's not asking that question.  He's asking if there's a way to execute code at the start of an ng-repeat cycle, but before the first entry is processed into the DOM.